# Logo image overflows out of navbar

Tags: html, css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a Twitter Bootstrap nav bar for this project

This is my navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand"><%= image_tag('Logo.jpg') %></a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-container-right">  
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "About",    about_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact",    contact_path %></li>
        <li>  
            <% if current_user.present? %>
                <%= link_to 'Sign Out',destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
            <% else %>
                <%= link_to 'Sign In', new_user_session_path %>
        </li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Register Now!', new_user_registration_path %><% end %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

The logo's dimensions are 250 x 250 pixels and it overflows out of the navigation bar. Is there a way to resize it automatically so that it fits within the elements dimensions? Or will I have to resize the image in a graphics editing software?

Comment: can you share a fiddle file? http://fiddle.jshell.net/

Comment: have you tried to use their class to make an image to responsive using 'img-responsive'? Ex: <img src='path' class="img-responsive"/>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
.navbar-header img {
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

Every image inside `navbar-header` will be scaled to its height.

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/YJw4H/

It's always a better practice to resize the image itself to improve the page load speed, by the way. You should also clean your code when you post a question to help people see your issue.